# Select the next element with a specific class after clicking on an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML looks like (spans inside the expandable text class are generated via JS)

```
<span class="expandable-text">
    <span class="more">read more</span>
    <span class="details">blablabla</span>
</span>
```

Current jQuery:

```
$('.expandable-text').on('click', '.more', function() {     
    setTimeout(function () {
        // bad as it selects all elements with that class...
        // $('.details').css('display', 'inline');
        $(this).next('span').css('display', 'inline');
    }, 50);
});
```

Also tried `$(this).parent().find('.details').css('display', 'inline');`

How should I be selecting that element with the `details` class, right next to the element I just clicked ?

Edit: Both the span elements inside the `expandable-text` are dynamically generated. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NTP9y/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.next('span')` is correct — if you know that each `.more` is necessarily followed by a `span.details` then you *could* omit the argument and just do `.next()`, but there's no difference if you don't.

The problem in your code is that `this` isn't properly scoped within the timeout callback.

The solution is to call `$(this)` and assign it to a variable outside of `setTimeout()`, then passing that variable into the timeout function:

```
$('.expandable-text').on('click', '.more', function() {
    var details = $(this).next('span');
    setTimeout(function () {
        details.css('display', 'inline');
    }, 50);
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping. I omitted saying that the spans are dynamically generated, please check http://jsfiddle.net/sfarsaci/NTP9y/

Comment: @Dany P: It looks like you're simply using a fiddle that someone else has provided that doesn't correspond to what you have in any way. That aside, using `.next()` should work all the same as I've stated in my answer.

Comment: It's the same fiddle as in my post, except that elements get dynamically generated. We can see on the fiddle that clicking read more doesn't trigger the display inline on the details element. But when the elements were directly in the HTML your code worked.

Comment: @Dany P: It's the same fiddle, and in that fiddle, the elements are *not* dynamically generated. Did you edit it? If so, make sure you saved/forked it correctly. It should generate a new link.

Comment: @Dany P: The way you're calling `.on()` should work for dynamically-generated elements - the problem lies in the fact that in that fiddle, you have a `br` directly following `.more`, so that's where `.next('span')` fails. If you replace it with `.siblings('span')`, it will work. See http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/NTP9y/3

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, one is `$(this).siblings('.details').css(...)` like here http://jsfiddle.net/sfarsaci/NTP9y/

Comment: Please check http://jsfiddle.net/sfarsaci/NTP9y/, I omitted saying that the spans are dynamically generated.